Python simpledialog location and hide blank
This is my code
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import simpledialog
root = tk.Tk()
# root.withdraw()
root.geometry("340x100+50+500")
user_input = simpledialog.askfloat(title="输入框", prompt="请输入内容：", parent=root, initialvalue=34)
user_input = user_input * 60
root.destroy()

When it's run, there was a blank form underneath it, and I wanted to hide it, so I added a piece of code
root.withdraw()

But the root.geometry("340x100+50+500") is not work
so how i do the root.withdraw() and root.geometry("340x100+50+500") both work?

why does it matter what the geometry is if the window is hidden?

Because I want to control where the simpledialog.askfloat popup is


When it's run, there was a blank form underneath it, and I wanted to
hide it

Pay attention to @Bryan Oakley and @acw1668
The problem can be fixed.
Pay attention to @Bryan Oakley and @acw1668
Move root.withdraw() after root.geometry(...)
Snippet:
:
root.geometry("340x100+50+500")
root.withdraw()
:

Screenshot:


import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import simpledialog
root = tk.Tk()
root.wm_attributes('-alpha', 0.0)
root.geometry("340x100+50+500")
user_input = simpledialog.askfloat(title="输入框", prompt="请输入内容：", parent=root, initialvalue=34)
user_input = user_input * 60
root.destroy()

add root.wm_attributes('-alpha', 0.0) it's work

What is the point of setting the alpha option of an already hidden window?
